# Calling XGetErrorText() from X11 error handler

Tags: x11

Is it safe to call XGetErrorText from a error handler set by XSetErrorHandler?

E.g.

```
int errorHandler(Display *dpy, XErrorEvent *err)
{
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    XGetErrorText(dpy, err->error_code, buf, BUFLEN);
    printf("%s\n", buf)
    return 0;
}

XSetErrorHandler(errorHandler);
```

I'm asking because the man page says you should not call any functions (directly or indirectly) on the display that will generate protocol requests but it does not tell if XGetErrorText does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XGetErrorText` doesn't generate any server traffic. It's not supposed to: the server doesn't know your locale, for example, and cannot supply localised messages. `XLib` can, and indeed does with a couple of local Xrm database lookups.

The source code of `XGetErrorText` can be viewed e.g. [here](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libX11/tree/src/ErrDes.c). We can see that `XGetErrorText` calls `XGetErrorDatabaseText`, and this latter function is not even using its `dpy` parameter.

Each X extension provides its own error-event-to-error-string translation function. This function does accept a `dpy` parameter, but, just like `XGetErrorDatabaseText` is not supposed to use it too generate any server traffic. This error-handling function is by default generateed by the `XEXT_GENERATE_ERROR_STRING` macro [here](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libXext/tree/include/X11/extensions/extutil.h), which just encapsulates another call to `XGetErrorDatabaseText`.

Comment: This answers my question. Indeed it was the Display* parameter that made me wonder. But apart from looking at the source (which in it self is on principle a good thing to do) I would not know how to figure it out.
Thanks